# getCoG() returns (0, 0, 0)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

I am trying to find center of mass by doing the following

> std::cout << this->model->GetLink("leg1")->GetInertial()->GetCoG() << std::endl;

but I only get 0,0,0. Is there any reason why it's happening? Maybe the reference frame is the link it self, instead of the world frame?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8875/getcog()-returns-(0,-0,-0)/) by [mugenHexapod](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1197/mugenhexapod/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2015-06-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Correct, the center of mass is expressed with respect to the link, and the link pose with respect to the parent model.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mugenHexapod](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1197/mugenhexapod/) on 2015-06-07**:
what is the suggested way to find the CoG with respect to the world frame?

**Comment by [mugenHexapod](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1197/mugenhexapod/) on 2015-06-07**:
is this->model->GetLink("leg1")->GetWorldCoGPose().pos the right way for getting the CoG wrt world frame?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-06-07**:
It looks right.

**Comment by [mugenHexapod](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1197/mugenhexapod/) on 2015-06-07**:
thank you!